# how to get records based on date of birth

Tags: sql-server

I need to calculate the upcoming birthday and has to send the birthday wish to them. I am unable to retrieve the records from the database having field for date of birth.

Can anyone give me the query using which i can get records having birthday in next 7 days based on DateOfBirth field in SQL Server 2005

Thanks in advance

Comment: Need some more information about table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ...
FROM...
WHERE DATEDIFF(dd, 
            CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(MONTH(DateOfBirth) AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(DAY(DateOfBirth) AS VARCHAR) AS DATETIME), 
            GETDATE()) <= 7
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM
   TABLE
WHERE
    DATEPART(dy, DateOfBirth) - DATEPART(dy, GETDATE()) > 0 AND
    DATEPART(dy, DateOfBirth) - DATEPART(dy, GETDATE()) <=7
```